# Trouble selecting inputs whose names begin with a certain character sequence

Tags: jquery, input, selector

I’m having trouble with my Jquery selectors (using v 1.11).  I want to select all inputs whose name begins with a certain character sequence (“my_object”).  In the console, if I just select the inputs themselves, I get a bunch of items …

```
$(':input')
[<input name=​"utf8" type=​"hidden" value=​"✓">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"my_object[id]​" id=​"my_object_id" value=​"65">​, 
 <input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[name]​" id=​"my_object_name">​, 
 <input class=​"datepicker hasDatepicker" type=​"text" name=​"my_object[day]​" id=​"my_object_day">​, 
 <input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[distance]​" id=​"my_object_distance">​,
<select name=​"my_object[distance_unit]​" id=​"my_object_distance_unit">​…​</select>​, 
<select name=​"my_object[hour]​" id=​"my_object_hour">​…​</select>​, 
<select name=​"my_object[minute]​" id=​"my_object_minute">​…​</select>​, 
<select name=​"my_object[second]​" id=​"my_object_second">​…​</select>​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[address]​[city]​" id=​"my_object_address_city">​, 
<select name=​"state" id=​"state">​…​</select>​, 
<select id=​"country_country_id" name=​"country[country_id]​" style>​…​</select>​,
<input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[my_object_times_attributes]​[0]​[overall_rank]​" id=​"my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_overall_rank">​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[my_object_times_attributes]​[0]​[age_group_rank]​" id=​"my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_age_group_rank">​,
<input type=​"text" name=​"my_object[my_object_times_attributes]​[0]​[gender_rank]​" id=​"my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_gender_rank">​, 
<input type=​"hidden" name=​"my_object[my_object_times_attributes]​[0]​[time_in_ms]​" id=​"my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_time_in_ms">​, 
<input type=​"hidden" id=​"_method" name=​"_method" value=​"patch">​, 
<input type=​"submit" name=​"commit" value=​"Save" class=​"button">​]
```

but once I try and get the names using the selector, I get nothing …

```
$(':input[name^=”my_object”]')
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?  I can see that the names start with the sequence I expect so I’m confused about what else I need to do.

Comment: Don't use a word processor to edit Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong thing are those quotes. Get rid of them - you're attempting yo match the input which name begins with `”my_object”`, not `my_object`.

```
$(':input[name^=my_object]')
```

Or use the legit ones, like `"`.